# Adding trailing slash to S3 bucket URL without List permissions results in empty file download instead of Access Denied

Tags: security, permissions, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 test bucket configured at [https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/[my](https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/%5Bmy) bucket]/. I want directory listing to be turned off, and this is how my permissions for this bucket look:

[image: S3 bucket permissions here]

And when I go to the root directory of the bucket, I do indeed get access denied. All good so far.

Inside of that bucket I have a subdirectory called message. If I go to [https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/[my](https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/%5Bmy) bucket]/message, I (again) get the expected Access Denied error. But if I add a trailing slash, like [https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/[my](https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/%5Bmy) bucket]/message/, then instead of access denied, my browser downloads an empty file.

Does anyone know why this would be the case? Thanks!

Comment: My best guess is that the trailing slash indicates a folder request, whereas without the trailing slash it's requesting an object that you dont't have access to.